# Concrete example of charting a topological manifold without specifying a connection

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

I have been trying to understand manifold theory for a long time now, and every single example of charting a manifold I see is after giving the structure of a connection on it. For instance , consider Visual Differential Geometry chapter-2 in Tristan Needham where he shows the various projections of sphere onto plane, and finally, charting the pseudo sphere.

The issue I have with this is, when we say how the manifold actually sits in space, we have already specified a connection. Actually if one thinks about it, it seems impossible to chart a manifold without specifying a connection through geometrical method as without it, we don't have a concrete entity to draw lines and angles on! ([Eg: If we remove the connection coefficients aspect, then sphere and ellipse are same as topological manifolds acc. to the Schuller lectures](https://youtu.be/2eVWUdcI2ho?t=385))

Could I be directed to a source which gives an explicit explanation of how such a construction without any geometric concreteness could be done? It seems impossible to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "we have already specified a connection"? What is a connection for you anyway?

Comment: Map between $(p,q)$ tensor field to $(p,q)$ tensor field specified by some connection coefficients @YoungMath on a differentiable manifold level, you can't distinguish a sphere or ellipse as they are same in the sense of diffeomorphism

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The stereographic projection of the sphere, for example, does not need the notion of a connection. A connection is simply a further structure you put on the manifold (more precisely on the tangent bundle).

Comment: To derive the actual expression for how to do the stereographic projection, you put the sphere on top of the origin and argue by geometry how the points on the plane correspond to points on sphere. Now, when you said how the sphere looks like for this arguement, then you've implicitly have taken the connection for granted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The issue I have with this is, when we say how the manifold actually sits in space, we have already specified a connection.

Absolutely not. A manifold is first of all a set of points. On top of that we have a topology. On top of that there is an atlas of charts. (Equivalently, one can start with a set, and a bunch of charts, and then use that to define the topology). A connection has nothing to do with this at all. A connection is about how to move vectors from a vector space attached at one point in the manifold to a vector space attached to a different point of the manifold. By this very heuristic definition, and the order of presentation it should already be clear logically that connections have nothing at all to do with the definition of a manifold or its charts.

I'm not sure I understand your objection to the sphere. $S^n$ is first of all just a set of points. The most common definition is that it is a certain subset of $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$. Also, regarding the comments of Frederic Schuller regarding the sphere and ellipse being the same, all that means is the two spaces are homeomorphic (and also diffeomorphic once we equip both spaces with their natural differentiable structures). What is true is that it is impossible to talk about lengths and angles on such manifolds without a metric tensor, and it is impossible to talk about "straightness" without specifying a connection.

Anyway, if you don't like spheres, consider the following. Define a relation $\sim$ on $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ by saying $x\sim y$ if and only if there exists a $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $x=\lambda y$. You can easily verify this is an equivalence relation. Consider the quotient set of all equivalence classes. This is denoted $\Bbb{R} P^n:= (\Bbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})/\sim$, and is called the ($n$-dimensional) real projective space.

Note that $\Bbb{R} P^n$ is not defined as a subset of some cartesian space, rather it is a quotient space. On this space, one can define the quotient topology, so now we have a topological space. We can go further and define a smooth structure as follows. For each $i\in\{1,\dots, n+1\}$, let $U_i:=\{[(x^1,\dots, x^{n+1})]\in\Bbb{R} P^n\,:\, x^i\neq 0\}$, and define $\phi_i:U_i\to \Bbb{R}^n$ as
\begin{align}
\phi_i([x^1,\dots, x^{n+1}])&=\left(\frac{x^1}{x^i}, \dots,
\frac{x^{i-1}}{x^i}, \frac{x^{i+1}}{x^i},\dots, \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^i}\right)
\end{align}
The map $\phi_i$ is well-defined due to the nature of the equivalence relation. The claim is that $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ forms a $C^{\infty}$ atlas for $\Bbb{R} P^n$. Therefore, the maximal atlas containing this is what defines the smooth structure.

Here, $\Bbb{R} P^n$ is most naturally presented as a quotient space, NOT a subset of $\Bbb{R}^k$ for some $k$. Also, I didn't need a connection at all to define the charts (again that would be absurd).

Comment: In another lecture, he explicitly mentions that only with the connection can we differentiate the sphere and the ellipse. Let me find it.

Comment: Heck, we can go further. Let $V$ be any (real or complex say) $n$-dimensional vector space. We can define the set $G_k(V)$ to be the set of all $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$. Clearly as a set, $G_k(V)$ is a very complicated object: it's elements are subspaces (i.e $G_k(V)$ is a set of sets). But still, $G_k(V)$ has a natural smooth manifold structure (look up Grassmanians).

Comment: @Buraian He doesn't mean "only" in that the connection is the only thing which differentiates them. What he meant is something along the following lines. Think of a sphere of radius 1 and a sphere of radius 2. We obviously want to think of them as smaller and bigger, and hence different. However, from the purely differential/topological perspective, they are equivalent (there exist diffeomorphisms/homeomorphisms). However, these manifolds (once equipped with the canonical Riemannian metric) are not isometrically isomorphic Riemannian manifolds, and this is likely what he's alluding to.

Comment: So the level of "sameness" or "differentness" depends on how much structure you wish to consider/ignore.

Comment: [6:36](https://youtu.be/2eVWUdcI2ho?t=385), he shows how only when he puts on the very specific choice of $\nabla$ does the sphere become the sphere and the ellipse the ellipse as we think it in 3D space (I added a lot of words, but it's wht I understood). Lemme go over what you said again.

Comment: I have a feeling you cheated a little bit because the example you took was already very similar to $R^d$ but it's fine I suppose. I need to go over your answer a bit more carefully. I'll do it by tmmrw hopefully.

Comment: I can definitely cook up more complicated ways of presenting the definition of $\Bbb{R} P^n$, but clearly that won't help. I think the issue you're facing is that the only examples of manifolds you've seen are embedded submanifolds of $\Bbb{R}^k$ (spheres, ellipsoids, hyperbolas, parabolas etc, basically level sets of nice enough functions, or graphs of smooth functions). However, there are many other natural manifolds which appear, and they are not embedded in $\Bbb{R}^k$ (sure any manifold can always be embedded into a high-enough dimensional $\Bbb{R}^k$, but that's besides the point).

Comment: So, you just have to look up more examples of manifolds which are not embedded in $\Bbb{R}^k$: projective spaces, Grassmanians, Klein bottle are the first few examples people study.

Comment: Thank you . One requestion: IF you have checked out time, could you please expand out what he is saying in that time stamped link detailed? I will check out everything as a whole tommorrow. And, I guess you're right. I think one issue is that those type of abstract manifold are also hard to visualize so not many author give that as an example for intuition. If you have simple suggestion of where I can read of thing you said that'd be nice too

Comment: he's alluding to the idea that curvature is a property of a connection (which in every case of interest in those lectures is the Levi-Civita connection, i.e you have a metric tensor in the game, even though he hasn't defined that yet); and this is the subject of that lecture: parallel transport and curvature. Intuitively, one of the things which makes a small sphere different from a big sphere is its curvature. Likewise, an ellipse is "a squashed sphere", so it has a different curvature as well. This goes back to my previous comment about sameness depending on how much structure you consider

Comment: On your first point: if I got this right sphere and ellipse when seen as sitting in space, they are actually different set of points but they are equivalent due to being able to be mappable to each other as differentiable manifolds. Since they are different set of points you can chart them.. but if you want to say how exactly one is different from the other you need the connection, correct? @peekaboo

Comment: @Buraian sure, but literally speaking, the sphere and ellipse are different sets of points, so that's obviously a difference (but not a very convincing one). You're right that the connection (which comes from the metric, i.e the geometry of the surfaces) allows us to describe what is the geometric difference between these spaces (one is curved slightly differently than the other). Again, sameness/differentness all depends on the level of scrutiny (how many check boxes are you trying to satisfy).